# Tkinter scrollbar is not having the dragable part

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Code:

```py
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import ttk


root=Tk()
# creating the main frame
main_frame=Frame(root)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
mycanvas=Canvas(main_frame)
mycanvas.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=1)
myscrollbar=Scrollbar(main_frame,orient=VERTICAL,command=mycanvas.yview)
myscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)
mycanvas.bind("<Configure>",lambda e: mycanvas.configure(scrollregion=mycanvas.bbox("all")))
secondframe=Frame(mycanvas)
mycanvas.create_window((0,0),window=secondframe,anchor="nw")
labell=Label(secondframe,text="run this")
labell.grid(row=3,column=4)
root.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image]

Everything is working fine, except that dragable part to scroll. Please help me with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work just fine, all you have to do is have more items in the frame such that it needs to have be full to be dragged. To see it for yourself, change your label with:

```
for a in range(50):
    Label(secondframe,text=a).grid(row=a,column=4)
```

You will notice the scrollbar can be used now. Without having alot of "items", there is no need for a y-scrollbar and hence it is grayed out.

Comment: oh ok got it, i just started to learn tkinter scrollbar

Comment: @Hafeezh Just to be on the safe side, try replacing the label with this and confirm :D

Comment: i wanted to ask you, is there any way to have the scroll bar only for a certain height in the y axis

Comment: @Hafeezh Well, ive not made a single scrollbar in my whole tkinter journey, lol, so im not sure.